# int** a = new int*[n](); What does this function do?

Tags: c++

```cpp
int** a = new int*[n]();
```

I can't find any explanation for this code, all I find is explanations for code like  `int *array = new int[n];`. I understand it but I can't completely figure out the code above. What does it mean?

Comment: Why don't you try writing an explanation of the first snippet? In case there is any confusion there.

Comment: What I understand is: new allocates memory for n numbers of int, and the pointer(array) is storing its address. Is this accurate? Though my concepts are not completely clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you (should) know, `int *a = new int[n];` allocates an array of `int`s with size `n`.

So, in general, `T *a = new T[n];` allocates an array of `T`s with size `n`.

Now if you substitute `T = int *`, you'll get `int **a = new int*[n];`, which allocates an array of `int *`s (that is, of pointers to `int`).

Adding `()` on the right zeroes every pointer in the array (otherwise they would be uninitialized).

Comment: Great explanation! Thnx m8, I understood everything other than the addition of (), so could you elaborate: Adding () on the right zeroes every pointer in the array (otherwise they would be uninitialized)?

Comment: @roHit If you don't add `()`, every pointer in the array will be uninitialized (i.e. have some random value). If you add `()`, every pointer in the array will be null. It's called [*value-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Answer (score 1):

create a pointer to an array of size n, where every entry is a pointer to integer

You'll get an array of pointers

Answer (score 0):

As you (should) know, `int *a = new int[n];` allocates an array of ints with size n.

So, in general, `T * a = new T[n];` allocates an array of Ts with size n.

Now if you substitute `T = int *`, you'll get `int **a = new int*[n];`, which allocates an array of `int *s` (that is, of pointers to int).

Adding () on the right zeroes every pointer in the array (otherwise they would be uninitialized).